# How can I get the actual appointment / meeting time from the reminder?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

In `ThisOutlookSession`, I have added code for Reminders:

```
Private Sub obj_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
  If (ReminderObject.Caption = "Daily Update") then 
    ' Do some thing. 
    ' Check if the reminder is for today only 
    If (ReminderObject.OriginalReminderDate = Now) Then
       'Do more things
    end if
  end if
end sub
```

Since my reminder is set to alert 15 minutes before the event, the event is fired 15 minutes before.

How can I get the  actual appointment / meeting time from the reminder?

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the `Reminder` event instead you will get the actual `AppointmentItem`, `MailItem`, `ContactItem`, or `TaskItem` which the event pertains to.

Answer (score 0):

Read `Reminder.Item` property and cast it appropriately (e.g. to `AppointmentItem` object).